# TestFlight app freezes on startup

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios6, testflight

While running an app distributed via TestFlight, it keeps freezing on the splash screen. I have created a new distribution certificate and an Ad Hoc provisioning profile to go with it.

I believe that I have done all the necessary steps in the project itself:

- I added the TestFlight library and libz.dylib
- I entered the two lines needed into my appdelegate
- I changed the release signing entity to my distribution profile

Uploading it to TestFlight works like a charm, so does downloading and installing the app to the test phone. 
When I run it though, it freezes on the splash screen. No crashes or errors...

Any ideas?

Comment: Try running it in a debugger and when it freezes, press "pause" and see where the threads are in the stack.

Comment: The app runs perfectly when it is compiled the usual way, it is only when distributed via TestFlight it freezes!

Comment: Is this the same device (testflight vs. xcode debugger)?

Comment: same here ! App freezes after TestFlight download ! Also, Apple rejects my app from the App review due to the same reason. Extremely frustrating. I have no clue what to do with my Flutter App (iOS13.3).... Any ideas highly appreciated !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it. Apparently, you can not have your iPhone connected to the computer while running the app installed via TestFlight.

Comment: I've unplugged my iPhone from my computer and re-installed the app via TestFlight and still it crashes right after launch image? Weird, I just ran the app on my device through xCode and everything was working perfectly..'